# jQuery autocomplete code customize

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, limit

i have made the below code for jQuery autocomplete.

Below first part is a code so that i get the suggestion when i click on input with id #project. I too have second part of code that limits the number of suggestion. How can i merge  them so that both features can work. I have put second part in first but first part stops working.

```
$(function() {
var projects = [
     {
        //your each suggestion link here
        value: "www.facebook.com",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library"  
        //your alternate texts here
    },
    {
        value: "jquery-ui 1 ",
        label: "jQuery UI 1",
        desc: "the official,  user ,interface, library for jQuery"           
    },
    {
        value: "jqueryme 2",
        label: "jQueryme 2",
        desc: "the negative, user interface, river, Maniram,for jQuery"         
    },      
    {
        value: "jqueryme 3",
        label: "jQueryme 3" ,
        desc: "the negative, user interface, river, Maniram,for jQuery"         
    },      
    {
        value: "jqueryme 4",
        label: "jQueryme 4",
        desc: "the negative, user interface, river, Maniram,for jQuery"         
    },      
    {
        value: "jqueryme 5",
        label: "jQueryme 5",
        desc: "the negative, user interface, river, Maniram,for jQuery"         
    },
    {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine"          
    }
];

function lightwell(request, response) {

function hasMatch(s) {
        return s.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase())!==-1;
    }
    var i, l, obj, matches = [];

    if (request.term==="") {
        response([]);
        return;
    }

    for  (i = 0, l = projects.length; i<l; i++) {
        obj = projects[i];
        if (hasMatch(obj.label) || hasMatch(obj.desc)) {
            matches.push(obj);
        }
    }
    response(matches);      

}

$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
    //number of characters to be typed for user here
    minLength: 3,
    source: lightwell,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );          
        window.open(ui.item.value,'_self');            
        return false;
    }
})

.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label )
        .appendTo( ul );
};  

});
```

Second part to show suggestion limit of 2, When i insert this code above, only two suggestions work but other functionality with 'desc' doesnot work.

```
$("#project").autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(projects, request.term);

    response(results.slice(0, 2));
}
});
```

how can i merge together so i can have work done?? help please

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `lightwell` function by adding a final `slice`.

Code:

```
function lightwell(request, response) {

    function hasMatch(s) {
        return s.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    }
    var i, l, obj, matches = [];

    if (request.term === "") {
        response([]);
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0, l = projects.length; i < l; i++) {
        obj = projects[i];
        if (hasMatch(obj.label) || hasMatch(obj.desc)) {
            matches.push(obj);
        }
    }
    response(matches.slice(0, 2));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/VYy7U/